# HTML5 pushState the element disappears

Tags: jquery, pushstate

I'm trying to do a pushState website, well, the problem is all of a in .nav disappear.

I don't know what's going on, maybe is the jquery version, so here's my code of index.html:

```
        <!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/application.js"></script>
    <title>One</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <audio controls>
<source src="mp.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
    <div id="body">
<div id="menu">
<div class="nav">
<a href="two.html">d</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and application.js:

```
$(function(){
    var replacePage = function(url) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data){
                var dom = $(data);
                var title = dom.filter('title').text();
                var html = dom.filter('.nav').html();
                $('title').text(title);
                $('.nav').html(html);
            }
        });
    }

    $('a').live('click', function(e){
        history.pushState(null, null, this.href);
        replacePage(this.href);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $(window).bind('popstate', function(){
        replacePage(location.pathname);
    });
});
```

here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vD5Ex/)

two.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/application.js"></script>
    <title>One</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <audio controls>
<source src="mp.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
    <div id="body">
<div id="menu">
<div class="nav">
<a href="index.html">djbghasighaslashb</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It probably doesn't help, but you could use some newer jQuery version.

Comment: I tried it too, exactly with version 2.0.3 but it gives me the same error

Comment: what does your `two.html` page look like, and have you also printed(`console.log`) out your `html` variable to make sure it contains what you think it will?

Comment: Hm, how is your response structured? Like `<title>..</title><div class="nav">..</div>`? Are these elements wrapped into anything else? If yes, then you should use `dom.find()` instead of `dom.filter()`.

Comment: @PatrickEvans i've updated it.

Comment: @biziclop I've tried it and it works right now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be useful to wrap the full html response into a root element if you are not sure if the desired elements are at root level or deep down somewhere in the dom tree:

```
success: function( data ){

  // create a single container element, and put the html response into it
  var dom = $('<div>').html( data );

  // now you never have to use .filter(), just .find()
  var title = dom.find('title').text();
  var html  = dom.find('.nav').html();
  ...
}
```

Comment: Right!, thanks, well i only changed dom.find('title') to dom.filter('title')